# AS3 game running slow (many objects)

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

ok so I am creating a tower defense game.I was wondering how do i remove objects that I do not require anymore (i.e lets say a bullet object has hit a target, at the moment all im going is setting the object to invisible). Starts to get slow after about 1.5K objects.

I have done a bit of research, however their doesn't seem to be any ubiquitous method. What do you guys recommend.

thanks

Comment: Are you using any game libraries or is this all just on the the normal display stack? you are setting the .visible property to false?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [Object Pools](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=as3+object+pool&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the object from the stage, and ensure all references to it are set to removed.  This includes removing event listeners, child display objects and stopping the execution of any internal code. Then the objects will become eligible for [garbage collection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html).

So for example:

```
if(myBullet has hit tower) {
    removeChild(myBullet);
    myBullet.removeEventLister(someEvent, someFunction);
    myBullet.stopSpinning();
    myBullet = null;
}
```

Comment: Also, if your bullet has any internal display objects, they will also need to be removed from the bullet, otherwise the bullet's childen's parent property is enough to keep it from being collected by garbage collection.